# Picking subset in python and changing values of subset

Tags: python, random

I have a numeric vector of length x, all values in the vector are currently 0. I want it to randomly assign y of these values to equal 1, and x-y of these values to equal 0. Any fast way to do this? My best guess right now is to have a RNG assign each value to 0 or 1, sum up the string and, if the sum does not equal y, start all over again.

Can I use random.choice(vector,y) and then assign the elements that were picked to equal 1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a function called `random.sample()` which, given a sequence of items, will give you back a certain number of them randomly selected.

```
import random
for index in random.sample(xrange(len(vector)), y): # len(vector) is "x"
    vector[index] = 1
```

Another way to do this would be to combine a list of `x` 0's and `y` 1's and shuffle it:

```
import random
vector = [0]*(x-y) + [1]*y  # We can do this because numbers are immutable
vector.shuffle()
```

Comment: I was just going to post the second answer.  Spent some time testing which was faster, and it turns out the shuffle wins by about 30% for vector of len 10 to 1000.  Didn't test beyond that.

Comment: @sberry It probably depends on the ratio of x to y.

Comment: y/x is about 1.2.  Thanks!

Comment: @Amber: certainly it does.  I was using a ratio of 1:1.

Comment: @sberry Yeah, for 1:1 shuffle likely wins simply due to not having to create an extra list (for returning from `random.sample()`) and instead being able to shuffle in-place. For smaller ratios `random.sample()` might very well win due to not having to shuffle a large base list.